# R Plot Numeric Variable vs Days of the Week

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, plot

I have a dataframe with two columns, Global Active Power is a numeric column and DateTime is a datetime type column. When I execute the command plot(DateTime,Global Active Power), I automatically get the days of the week as ticks on the x axis.
1. Can someone explain how this is happening?
2. Also, when I run plot(as.factor(weekdays(DateTime)),Global Active Power), I do not get the same plot, instead I get a boxplot.

[image: Global Active Power vs Day of Week]

Comment: please share `dput(head(DateTime))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DateTime` column has its dates and times all within a 48-hour period, so R chooses the day of the week as the most appropriate x axis labels for you. You can change this formatting to whatever you like.

Since your example did not include any data, I've had to create some dummy data to show how this works:

```r
set.seed(69)
x  <- (as.POSIXct("2020-05-29 10:30:00") + 1:(24 * 60) * 300)[1:1000]
y  <- rpois(1000, 50 * sin(seq(0, 12, length.out = 1000))^2) / 10
df <- data.frame(DateTime = x, `Global Active Power` = y)
```

So plotting this data, we get a similar layout to the plot in your question:

```
plot(df$DateTime, df$Global.Active.Power, type ="l", xlab ="Date", ylab ="Power")
```

[image]

Now, if I want to format with, say, the date, then I would draw the plot without an x axis then add a formatted axis like this:

```r
plot(df$DateTime, df$Global.Active.Power, 
     type = "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Power")

axis.POSIXct(1, df$DateTime, format = "%d %b")
```

[image]

As for why your plot changes to a boxplot when you change the x axis to a factor variable according to the day of the week, you have transformed your time variable from a continuous to a discrete variable. There are only two weekdays in your data, so you will only have two points on your x axis where data can appear. R chooses a boxplot here because otherwise your plot would just be a mess, as you can see if I change the date-times to just dates:

```
plot(as.Date(df$DateTime),df$Global.Active.Power)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>